# python dynamic object query

Tags: python, arrays, object, dictionary

I have a python object structured like:

```
tree = {
    "a": {
        "aa": {
            "aaa": {},
            "aab": {},
            "aac": {}
        },
        "ab": {
            "aba": {},
            "abb": {}
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "ba": {}
    },
    "c": {}
}
```

And a set of lists of strings like:

```
arr_1 = ["a", "ab"]
arr_2 = ["b", "ab"]
arr_3 = ["a", "ab", "aba"]
```

Each list defines a path of keys in the tree and I want to determine whether the list describes a valid path through the tree or not.

Currently I can achieve a case by case answer like so:

```
tree[arr_1[0]][arr_1[1]] # Returns correct object
tree[arr_2[0]][arr_2[1]] # Returns error
tree[arr_3[0]][arr_3[1]][arr_3[2]] # Returns correct object
```

Though this does not satisfy my requirements. I'd much prefer one function which will search the tree for the keys in any given list.

The following function is almost what I want but it does not handle lists of different lengths.

```
def is_valid(tree, arr):
    obj = tree[arr[0]][arr[1]]
    if len(obj) > 0:
        return(obj)
    else:
        return("No obj")
```

Currently this function outputs

```
is_valid(tree, arr_1) # Returns the correct result
is_valid(tree, arr_2) # Returns an error
is_valid(tree, arr_3) # Returns the same result as arr_1, which is incorrect
```

Can anyone help me expand this function to react dynamicically to the length of the `arr` argument?

Thanks!

Comment: First your 'set of dicts' is really a 'list of str'.  Second try to do `for key in arr:` to loop over the keys in `is_valid`.  Third, not sure if this is hw or the use case, but if you can, you can try creating an actual tree and searching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to utilize recursion. Every sub-tree is a tree and every sub-path is a path, so we can look at whether or not the first element in the path is valid then continue on from there.

```
def is_valid(tree, path):

    # base case. Any path would be valid for any tree
    if len(path) == 0:
        return True

    # the path must be invalid, no matter what comes before or after
    if not path[0] in tree:
        return False

    # look at the rest
    return is_valid(tree[path[0]], path[1:])
```

If you want the sub-tree a path describes you could instead do this:

```
def is_valid(tree, path):

    if len(path) == 0:
        return tree # the only difference
    if not path[0] in tree:
        return False
    return is_valid(tree[path[0]], path[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect!

Comment: If it answered your question I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer. Glad I could help.